# how to pass a variable as null in case statement in sql

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, sql-server-express

how to pass "@abo is null" and "@rh is null" in this query....this gives error...i'm doing this

```
select Distinct m.donorId,m.customid, FirstName + ' ' + Isnull(MiddleName,' ') + ' ' + isNull(LastName,'') as donorName  from m_donor as m inner join phlebotomyDetail as phy on m.DonorID=phy.DonorID left outer join  AVIRaw as avi ON  @prefix + RIGHT('000000' + CAST(m.DonorID AS VARCHAR(6)), 6) = avi.sampleid
            Where (m.donorId = @donorid OR @donorid is null) and
            (m.DOB =  @todate OR @todate Is Null) and
            (m.FirstName Like + '%' + @fullname + '%' OR m.MiddleName Like + '%' + @fullname + '%' OR m.LastName Like  +'%' + @fullname + '%' OR @fullname Is Null) and
            (m.cellPhone Like +'%' + @phone + '%' OR m.HomePhone Like + '%' + @phone + '%' OR m.WorkPhone Like + '%' + @phone + '%' OR m.OtherPhone Like + '%' + @phone + '%' OR  @phone Is Null) and
            (m.CustomID Like '%' + @custid OR @custid Is Null) AND
            (phy.BagNumber=@bagno OR @bagno is NULL) AND
            (phy.SegmentNo=@segno OR @segno is NULL ) AND
        (avi.result= CASE WHEN avi.AnalysisName = 'ABO' THEN @abo or @abo is null ELSE CASE WHEN avi.AnalysisName = 'RH' THEN left(@rh,3) or @abo is null END END)
```

Comment: Did you try using COALESCE ?

Answer (score 0):

i would try something like :

```
avi.result= 
CASE WHEN avi.AnalysisName = 'ABO' 
THEN @abo 
ELSE 
    CASE WHEN avi.AnalysisName = 'RH' 
    THEN left(@rh,3) 
    END 
END
```

the result of the case must be type compatible with the type of avi.result.

imho, you should put a ELSE in the second/inner case, or use the syntax:

```
avi.result= 
CASE avi.AnalysisName 
    WHEN 'ABO' THEN @abo  
    WHEN 'RH' THEN left(@rh,3)  
    ELSE 'DEF' 
END
```